# how to integrate multiple admob ids in one app

Tags: android, admob

We are a bunch of devs working on apps , i was wondering how to split revenue genarated from an app ,each developper has his own admob id , so we can rotate ads with a percentage , eg 30% for each one .

how it can be done ?

Answer (score 1):

So each of you have your own ad Unit ID's on admob. I think one easy way of going about it would be to create a random generated variable that correlates with the number of dev ID's so if you have 4 devs then create something like this:

```
var randomNumber:number = Random(1, 4);  //Random being a random generating function


if(randomNumber == 1)
{
   //Add one of the Devs ID's 
}else //so on and so on etc...
```

It wont split the profit but at least you will all get paid and it wont give the revenue to just one dev/

If that doesnt sound appealing just create the same if statement but not random so whenever another ad appears it goes to the next dev in the if statement and so on...

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

- First of all you need to **change your ad unit id in run time** and for
  that use `mAdView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);`
- Now to keep account for equal ad loads for each developer try to use **SharedPreference** to store the number of time an ad loads (for each dev).

  ```
  SharedPreferences sp;
  SharedPreferences.Editor ed;

  String d1="AD_UNIT_1";
  String d2="AD_UNIT_2";
  String d3="AD_UNIT_3";

  sp = getSharedPreferences("ads",0);
  ed = sp.edit();

  if(!sp.contains("AD_UNIT_1")){
   //Considering 3 developers..
   ed.putLong("AD_UNIT_1",0);
   ed.putLong("AD_UNIT_2",0);
   ed.putLong("AD_UNIT_3",0);
   ed.commit();
  }else{
   long dev1 = sp.getLong("AD_UNIT_1",0);
   long dev2 = sp.getLong("AD_UNIT_2",0);
   long dev3 = sp.getLong("AD_UNIT_3",0);
  }
  ```
- Find minimum of dev1, dev2 and dev3 and use it for example if dev1 is smaller then:-

  ```
  if(dev1<dev2 && dev1<dev3){
   //dev1 is smallest
   mAdView.setAdUnitId(d1);
   dev1=dev1+1;
   ed.putLong(d1,dev1);//update this change to shared preference
   }else if...//and so on for dev2 and dev 3
  ```
- Load this on every page load. This may be a bit complex but it will ensure that everyone's ad-unit is loaded equally.